# Вставка строки. Функция IsEmpty не видит пустую строку

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Код ниже предназначен для нахождения слова "world", проверки есть ли над ним пустая строка, если есть то выход из макроса, если нет то вставка пустой строки! Окончательно выбился из сил искать, ну что в этой простой строчке не так. Сам же макрос вставляет пустую строку и повторно следуя не видит её и опять вставляет новую пустую строку и так до бесконечности.

```
Sub Test()  

            Cells.Find(What:="world", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _  
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _  
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate  
                ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select   
            If IsEmpty(Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select) = True Then  
                End  
            Else  
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select  
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert   
                Selection.Rows.AutoFit  
            End If  
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильное применение оператора *IsEmpty*, он предназначен для переменных.

Обращение к объектам листа - медленная операция. Выделять ячейки не обязательно.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim r As Range
    ' ячейку со словом - в переменную
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:="world", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
    ' если над "world" пусто, вставляем строку
    If Cells(r.Row - 1, r.Column).Value <> "" Then Rows(r.Row - 1).Offset(1, 0).Insert
    Set r = Nothing ' освобождаем память
End Sub
```

Проверка всей строки зависит от конкретных данных. Если диапазон столбцов неизвестен, нужно заранее определить граничные столбцы диапазона.

Самое простое (и медленное) - счет значений (сумма, счет по условиям...) с применением функции листа:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r.Row - 1, 1), Cells(r.Row - 1, 50))) > 0 Then
```

По ячейкам строки можно пробежаться циклом:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim lClmn As Long
Dim b As Boolean
    lClmn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' столбцов в диапазоне
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:="world", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Set r = Range(Cells(r.Row - 1, 1), Cells(r.Row - 1, lClmn)) ' диапазон строки

    For Each c In r ' цикл по ячейкам диапазона
        If c.Value <> Empty Then b = True: Exit For ' поставили флаг и вышли из цикла
    Next c

    If b Then Rows(r.Row).Offset(1, 0).Insert  ' вставляем строку
    Set r = Nothing ' освобождаем память
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо большое, первый вариант вашего кода работает, но почему в главном, я вижу нерабочий вариант?

Comment: я немного поспешил, ваш код работает, но он определяет на пустоту, только Ячейку находящуюся выше найденной, а нужно просматривать всю строку. Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое ещё раз, это то что было нужно!